# How can I make a facebook app work only on my page?

Tags: php, facebook

I wrote an app that works as a page tab, but I don't want others to use it. Is it possible to make the app work only on my page?

Also, If it is possible to redirect the user to my page if he accessed the app through another page?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting a unique ID per tab page for a facebook app](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5302471/getting-a-unique-id-per-tab-page-for-a-facebook-app)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is somewhat crude but should work. This will check if the current page ID is your page ID and if not display an error message.

```
<?php
    // Include the Facebook PHP SDK
    require('includes/fbSDK/facebook.php');

    // Enter your app details
    $app_id = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
    $app_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId' => $app_id,
        'secret' => $app_secret,
        'cookie' => true
    ));

    $signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();

    // Get the curren page ID
    $page_id = $signed_request["page"]["id"];

    // Enter your page ID
    $mypageID = '123456789';

    if ($page_id == $mypageID):
        include('/your/app/files.php');
    elseif ($page_id != $mypageID):
        echo "This app only works on a single page!";
    endif;
?>
```

Here are some examples of what you can check for:

```
$page_id = $signed_request["page"]["id"];
$page_admin = $signed_request["page"]["admin"];
$like_status = $signed_request["page"]["liked"];
$country = $signed_request["user"]["country"];
$locale = $signed_request["user"]["locale"];
```

You can for example use this method to require someone to like a page before you show content.

Hope this helps!

Comment: wow, thank's! I used to check if a user liked the page with the graph api (checking on his likes). Your way is much simpler.

Comment: This is an extremely common question (this or 'how do i tell what page my app is loaded from') - could we promote this as an FAQ answer?